# What is Asp.net Core 2.1 Identity's LockoutEnabled property actually for?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using Asp.net Core 2.1 Identity and there is a property named "**LockoutEnabled**", for a second I thought this flag determines whether a user is locked out or not.  But the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutenabled?view=aspnetcore-2.1) says it is

> "a flag indicating if the user could be locked out"

So what is this property for?  And is the lock out feature actually implemented in this version of the library?  Thanks.

Comment: I think the idea is that you could flag an administrative user with that to prevent the admin user from ever being locked out automatically.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is used to enable a user lockout for a specific period of time.
If you set `LockoutEnabled` to `true` **and** add a [LockoutEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutend?view=aspnetcore-2.1) date, you'll prevent that user from logging in again until after the `LockoutEnd` date is reached.
If only the `LockoutEnabled` flag is set to `true`, with no `LockoutEnd` date set, it just means that the user can be locked out, but is not locked out.

Comment: Can I just turn it on manually to lock a user out?  Or is it solely for X failed login attempts to lock a user out?

Comment: @RayFan sure, if you set both those values manually, the user will be locked out.

Comment: I see, it works hand in hand with the LockoutEnd property, thank you.

Comment: Tip: If you want to PERMANENTLY lock out a user, you set the LockoutEnd to far in the future (like 200 years), as demonstrated in this blog: https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Lockout/

Comment: I searched and searched to reach this simple answer, thanx

Answer (score 11):

Once `LockoutEnd` has a future date then the user is considered locked out whether `LockoutEnabled` is `true` or `false`.  `LockoutEnabled` is used when determining if the current user *should* be locked out such as when entering too many incorrect passwords. In other words, if `LockoutEnd` has a date in the future then the user is locked out, even if `LockoutEnabled` is `false`, .